# Regex pattern is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching

I want to allow every character in my input field except ^<>%*()#!? and for this i am using this constraints.
for client side validation

```
final String regexpattern = "/[^<>%*()#!?]/";
```

for server side

```
 final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/[^<>%*()#!?]/");
```

but it is not working

Comment: Seems to me your regex will work, except that a return value of True means the input is invalid, and False means the input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In client side the pattern should be

```
regexpattern = /^[^<>%*()#!?]*$/
```

server

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[^<>%*()#!?]*$");
```

Comment: If you also don't want the `^` character, you have to use `[^<>%*()#!?^]`

Answer (score 0):

It is only for one character, you need to add "+" or "*" after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `^` and `$` in the pattern to specify the beginning and end of the string, otherwise it will only verify that there is at least one valid character in the string, not that all characters in the string are valid.

Also you need a multiplier for the character set, otherwise it will only match a string that is one character long. To allow zero or more characters you use `*`, and to allow one or more characters you use `+`. You can also use a range, for example `{2,10}` allows between 2 and 10 characters.

The `^` in the beginning of the set is to make it negative, so to disallow `^` you also need it among the characters in the set.

The slashes are delimiters for a regular expression literal. Either you write the pattern as a string, which you can use to create a regular expression object:

```
pattern = "^[^^<>%*()#!?]+$";
```

or you write it as a regular expression literal, which becomes a regular expression object:

```
regex = /^[^^<>%*()#!?]+$/;
```

Answer (score -2):

Some of those characters need to be escaped in regular expressions .

Try this :

```
final String regexpattern = /[\^<>%*()#!?]+/ ;


final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[\^<>%*()#!?]+") ;
```

Comment: No. There are way fewer special characters when you are inside of square brackets (http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: After further testing, it turns out it was just the ^ that needed escaping to produce correct results. Escaping the other special characters still works, even if it's unnecessary.